# What's the notice after the fixed term agreement has expired

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, landlord

Property is in England. I have tenant who has given me their notice, they had a fixed term agreement that expired a few months ago they were looking to buy a house so we agreed they could just let it expire. Rather than doing for another whole year. The contract throughout said we both had to give two months notice, I figured they still had to give me that now, even when it expired, they want one month. Who is right here?

Comment: Seems like a legal question rather than one that's principally about money.

Comment: So the contract expired, and you are now on a word-of-mouth good-will-gesture month-by-month rental?

Comment: @JonCuster That's not how it works in England & Wales; unless otherwise agreed, it will be a statutory periodic tenancy.

Answer (score 2):

First review the existing contract for anything that specifies what happens at the end of the term. I have seen ones that switch to month to month, others automatically extend by a whole year.

In the United states the rental law is done at the state level or even more local than that. So I took a look at the UK policies. I focused on England.

[Guidance How to rent: the checklist for renting in England Updated 24 March 2023](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/how-to-rent/how-to-rent-the-checklist-for-renting-in-england)

> 5. At the end of the fixed period If you want to stay
>
> If you want to extend your tenancy after any initial fixed period,
> there are a number of important issues to consider. Check Shelter’s
> website for advice. Do you want to sign up to a new fixed term?
>
> If not, you will be on a ‘rolling periodic tenancy’. This means you
> carry on as before but with no fixed term. Your tenancy agreement
> should say how much notice you must give the landlord if you want to
> leave the property – one month’s notice is typical. Shelter publishes
> advice on how you can end your tenancy.

I then went to the shelter website [How to end a periodic tenancy](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/private_renting/ending_a_periodic_tenancy/how_much_notice):

> How much notice
>
> You can give your landlord a legal notice called a 'notice to quit' to
> end a rolling tenancy.
>
> This is a more formal option. Your tenancy will end legally if you
> follow the rules on how much notice and where to send it.
>
> A legal notice must:
>
> - be in writing
> - give the right amount of notice
> - end on the correct day
>
> Here is an example of a notice to quit.
>
> A legal notice ends your tenancy and your right to live in your home.
>
> Joint tenancies will end for all tenants even if only one of you gives
> notice.
>
> You cannot withdraw a valid notice if you change your mind.
>
> Your landlord may agree to let you or other joint tenants stay on
> after a notice ends. Minimum notice periods
>
> You need to give at least:
>
> - 1 month if your rent is due monthly
> - 4 weeks if your rent is due weekly
>
> You can usually give the minimum notice to end your tenancy if your
> most recent agreement does not mention a longer notice period or if
> you've never had a written agreement.
>
> You may still need to give more than the minimum notice to make sure
> it ends on the right day. If your agreement says you must give more
> notice
>
> Your agreement might have a 'notice clause'.
>
> For example, if it says you have to give 2 months' notice.
>
> A notice clause might not apply after your fixed term has ended but
> sometimes it will. When will the longer notice apply?
>
> The longer notice period will only apply if either:
>
> - you never had a fixed term agreement
> - your agreement says it continues as a contractual periodic tenancy after the fixed term
>
> You can ignore a notice clause in your most recent agreement if both:
>
> - your fixed term has ended
> - your agreement does not say that it continues as a contractual periodic tenancy

It looks like the notice period is a month, unless the contract says that the notice period is longer during the periodic tenancy.